# Hyperledger Fabric: How to specify more than 1 CA in the CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS_FILES variable?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Lets say we have more than 1 trusted certificate authority for client TLS certificates. How does one specify more than 1 CA in the [CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS_FILES](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/enable_tls.html) variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done by separating the filenames with spaces and enclosing everythying in double quotes as follows e.g.,:

```
CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS_FILES="file1 file2 file3"
```

Also note that a peer node will obtain the `TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS` of other orgs in the network from the config block when it joins the channel. From [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/enable_tls.html):

> When a peer joins a channel, root CA certificate chains of the channel
>   members are read from the config block of the channel and are added to
>   the TLS client and server root CAs data structure.

So for the time interval between when a new peer node is instantiated and when it joins the channel, the logs will show authentication errors - the nodes from other orgs won't be able to connect to the peer. These errors can be ignored because the new peer node does not yet have the `TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS` of other orgs. The `CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS_FILES` is only supposed to have the certificates of those CA which are under your control and which provide TLS certs to peers and users of your org.

Comment: Man, These error messages on the peers have been bugging me for a while.Thank you..

Comment: you are welcome. it caused me lot of trouble myself.